# Rails 7 - ActiveStorage upload image from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7

My model:

```
class Mainphoto < ApplicationRecord

    has_one_attached :main_photo

end
```

Try to attache file like this in after_create for User model:

```
  Mainphoto.create!(:profile_id => self.profile.id)
  file = open("#{Rails.root}/public" + self.profile.avatar_photo_url)

  photo_url = self.profile.avatar_photo_url
  self.profile.mainphoto.main_photo.attach(io:file, filename:photo_url.slice(8..))
```

It generate url for photo like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMi
OnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBa2FyaWF0aW9uIn19- 
-021933e1f5b2afffc1fd3a3674847cee15e2754d/3184836_b37_2.jpg
```

and I get error like this:

```
ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError in 
ActiveStorage::Representations::RedirectController#show
ActiveStorage::FileNotFoundError
```

I check all post in here with keywords "activestorage upload image from url" but still I get this error.

I check database and there is correct Blob, correct attachment entry ... what's going on?

I DONT WANT TO DO IT LIKE THIS - BUT THIS WORK ... why?

```
  blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(
    io: File.open("#{Rails.root}/public" + photo_url),
    filename: photo_url.slice(8..),
    content_type: 'image'
    
  )  

  ActiveStorage::Attachment.create(
    name: 'main_photo',
    record_type: 'Mainphoto',
    record_id: self.profile.mainphoto.id,
    blob_id: blob.id
  )
```

Comment: Can you check if the main photo is attached to a `MainPhoto` object by
`MainPhoto.find(id).main_photo.attached?` ?

Comment: What's the content of `self.profile.avatar_photo_url` ? A `/` isn't missing after "#{Rails.root}/public" ? Like: "#{Rails.root}/public/".

Comment: Yes, If I check - if Mainphoto.where('id =?',f.id).first.main_photo.attached? return id ... it always return id.

Comment: content of self.profile.avatar_photo_url is - "/photos/3184836_b37_2.jpg"

Comment: @Wordica did you try to replace `open` with `File.open`?